# Snowflake Rollback

Tags: rollback, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just wanted to confirm that all the successfully completed jobs that completed after the 'Commit' (view image) and before "Rollback: were in fact 'rolled back' and thus the successfully queries are not reflected in the DB ie were redacted?.

[image]

If so any way to get those outputs back?

Comment: The Query History is intended to be a log of statements that occurred. Statements are not removed. You can cross-check with the UI History with the Snowflake view: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html#query-history-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're looking in the history tab?

I tried to recreate your scenario and issued 2 inserts and then a rollback - but the history tab was still showing both inserts, so I doubt anything is disappearing from it.

Also, not sure you're aware, but Snowflake has autocommit set to true by default. Have you altered this setting before trying to rollback?

On top of that, any DDL in Snowflake will also issue an autocommit (or even 2 of them, one prior to the DDL and another one after it's done).